# My admin password was changed!

Tags: router, account-security, administration

Can someone hack my router and change my admin password for Linksys router but leave my wifi passwords the same. Tried logging in on 3 different browser and 2 different computers. I also tried using the general admin password when initially setting it up in case it failed during an electrical surge. Not such why I couldn't log in to my router. Could it have been hacked?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it could be hacked especially if password was not strong enough or simply because of vulnerable router.

Make sure that firmware is *up-to-date*, then check logs if it has one and change password to something decent.

Here it is how to reset a password:

**Resetting the Linksys router to factory defaults**

> If you can't access the router's web-based setup page or forgot the
>   router's password, you may reset the router to its default factory
>   settings.  To do this, press and hold the Reset button for 10 seconds.
>
> **NOTE:**  Resetting your router to its default factory settings will also
>   reset your router's password.  The router's default password is
>   “admin” as for the username, just leave the field blank.
>
> **IMPORTANT:**  Make sure that the Power LED of the router is blinking
>   when you press the Reset button.  This indicates that the router is
>   being reset properly.
>
> **NOTE:**  The location of the Reset button may vary for every model. 
>   Older Linksys devices may require pressing and holding the Reset
>   button for 30 seconds to complete the reset process.

[Source](http://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=139791)

Comment: Thank you, I did have a really strong password for the admin and no username either. Many letters, numbers, and symbols. Would be very difficult I think but maybe not. Can this hacker get in if they know my isp address? Is there a way to catch them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if someone had access or guessed your router password they can/could change your router admin password and leave the wifi password the same, the attacker already knows the wifi password btw, needless to change that. However a quit reset should solve your problem. And it is good to have admin and wifi secure passwords.

Comment: Thank you, yes I do have pretty strong passwords for both admin and wifi.